# "No current user" from currentSession() AWS Amplify and Cognito

Tags: rest, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to get a REST API to return currentSession() from AWS Amplify and Cognito. The SignIn function works and i get a CognitoUser object returned, however, the getSession() function returns "No current user"

```
const Amplify = require('aws-amplify');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

Amplify.default.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: 'REGION',
        userPoolId: 'USERPOOLID',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'WEBCLIENTID',
        authenticationFlowType: 'AUTHTYPE',
    }
  })

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    async function signIn(username, password) {
        try {
            Amplify.Auth.signIn(username, password)
                .then(() => getSession())
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            res.json(error);
        }
    }

    async function getSession() {
        try {
            Amplify.Auth.currentSession()
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            res.json('error');
        }
    }

    signIn(req.body.u, req.body.p);
});
```

Help!

Comment: I have never used aws Amplify with node / expressJs, so i'm not entierly sure, but when I use aws amplify with a frontend framework like Angular or react, Amplify automatically stores the sign in credentials (jwt tokens etc) into localstorage in the browser. Since you are using a expressJs server, I don't think amplify have access to store it in the same way, and therefor no sign in credentials is stored after you run the Auth.signIn() method. Then no info is availiable when you run Auth.currentSession(). I think you therefor must move the Amplify part of your application to your frontend.

Comment: Thankyou - you're correct!